# Criar dois jar com o mesmo pom pelo eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar

Como criar um pom no maven que gere pelo eclipse dois arquivos .JARs, onde um terá os arquivos .class e o outro .jar terá os sources (arquivos .java) fazendo apenas um install. Exemplo:

Projeto

```
exemplo.jar
exemplo-src.jar
```

Exemplo do meu build:

```xml
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>

        <execution>
          <id>copy-installed</id>
          <phase>install</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <artifactItems>
              <artifactItem>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>${project.packaging}</type>
              </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>
            <outputDirectory>build/deploy</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </execution>         
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <version>3.0</version>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <encoding>iso-8859-1</encoding>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Maven tem um *plugin* especializado em gerar arquivos *jar* com os fontes do projeto (código fonte de produção ou de testes), o [Maven Source Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/).

Para gerar um *jar* com o código fonte de produção do projeto (arquivos *.java*), simplesmente configure este plugin na sua lista atual de plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Agora, ao invocar `mvn install`, será gerado também um jar `exemplo-version-sources.jar`.

Veja mais opções deste plugin [aqui](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html).

Answer (score 1):

Pra quem achar minha pergunta persistente achei uma solução otimizada. Digito o conteúdo abaixo no pom, e escreve

```
mvn clean source:jar package
```

Obs.: lembrando que o quando você cria o projeto já existe uma tag `<package>` não é necessário anunciá-lo, e caso não escolha nenhum package ele criará por padrão o "jar".

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```